# Is there a difference between .getDefaultInstance() and .newBuilder().build()?

Tags: kotlin, grpc

Doing this in Kotlin with gRPC API. Is there a difference between these two?

```
ApiRequest.newBuilder().build()
```

and

```
ApiRequest.getDefaultInstance()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated

> `static Foo getDefaultInstance()`: Returns the singleton instance of Foo. This instance's contents are identical to what you'd get if you called `Foo.newBuilder().build()` (so all singular fields are unset and all repeated fields are empty). Note that the default instance of a message can be used as a factory by calling its newBuilderForType() method.

Comment: This means that the default instance is a singleton and `newBuilder.build()` is not, which will matter if you're doing reference equality.